# Scoreboard is full,not at MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: apache, tomcat, httpd.conf, mod-jk

I an using Apache and Tomcat with mod-jk in my project. My web application is in Tomcat instances. I am using Apache jmeter for testing http load on tomcat. But I'm getting the error **Scoreboard is full,not at MaxRequestWorkers** even with 1000 threads.

```
[mpm_event:error] [pid 24313:tid 3075319488] AH00485: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers

[mpm_event:error] [pid 24313:tid 3075319488] AH00484: server reached MaxRequestWorkers setting, consider raising the MaxRequestWorkers setting
```

I've configured http-mpm for approximately 5000 threads.

httd-mpm.conf file is:

```
<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    ServerLimit              200
    StartServers             3
    MinSpareThreads          75
    MaxSpareThreads          250
    MaxClients               5000 
    ThreadsPerChild          25
    MaxRequestWorkers        5000
    MaxConnectionsPerChild   5000
</IfModule>
```

Can anybody please guide me what can be the problem in this configuration?

Comment: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53555

Comment: I concur that the above Bug is observed as a possible issue.   (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53555 ).  I also observed that the server will correct itself after a while and kill child processes (e.g. [Mon Nov 16 15:09:27.456764 2015] [core:error] [pid 1793:tid 139889295517568] AH00046: child process 8375 still did not exit, sending a SIGKILL

Answer (score 7):

It seems that Apache tries to gracefully finish some of the processes and hangs while doing so. It might be a problem of Apache (https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53555) or a problem of the application itself.

You can easily check it by looking at the server-status page of apache. In order to do that you need to enable the status.conf apache module. Then go to your-server.org/server-status. You will see all the processes and threads currently being used or gracefully finishing ("G"-state). If you have to many G's that don't go away, you found your problem. It would look sth like this:

[Too many threads gracefully finishing...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjaaV.png)

**The solution is pretty simple. Just set MaxConnectionsPerChild to 0 or comment it out (mpm_event.conf).** What this does is just let the process continue it's work without restarting it. That's a good thing in our case, since restarting the process let to the problem of having to many G's filling up the scoreboard and eventually crashing Apache.

Hope that helped.

Comment: This was a livesaver - completely fixed the problem on Apache 2.4.10, which comes with Debian (Jessie) 8.9. Thanks so much!

Comment: Still an issue with Apache 2.4.57.  Setting `MaxConnectionsPerChild 0` doesn't fix it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. I tried different Apache versions and MPMs.

I seem to get this alot with MPM Worker. Also error does not reoccur using Apache 2.2.2

Are you using cPanel? IF so try /upcp --force and increase StartServers to a higher amount like 50 as that's all I did to get this error away.

Answer (score 0):

[This serverfault Q&A](https://serverfault.com/questions/516373/what-is-the-meaning-of-ah00485-scoreboard-is-full-not-at-maxrequestworkers) suggests that the event mpm may have a bug.  The recommended settings for at least partial workaround:

```
StartServers 3
MinSpareServers 5
MaxSpareServers 10
ServerLimit 250
MaxRequestWorkers 250
MaxConnectionsPerChild 1000
KeepAlive Off
```

Answer (score -1):

Try EnableMMAP Off
in 00_default_settings.conf