# Apache 2 503 Error MaxRequestWorkers

Tags: apache2.4

It looks like my site is down... I'm getting a 503 error.

Apache2 Error Logs say:
Sun Apr 17 01:07:21.301617 2016] [mpm_event:error] [pid 11504:tid 140299448981376] AH00485: scoreboard is full, not at MaxRequestWorkers

I found not setting in apache2.conf to change this.

Thank you a lot for any help.

Regards,

Comment: First of all close the existing connections after first checking why they are stuck in the first place? Restarting your web server will resolve the immediate issue but you still need to investigate. Might be a dos

Comment: Hi i already did a service restart and a webserver restart... :-( no resolution yet...

Answer (score 0):

This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46273227/4435083

The solution might be pretty simple. Just set MaxConnectionsPerChild to 0 or comment it out (mpm_event.conf).

Comment: yes maybe pretty simple but it doesn't work. my Apache version: 2.4.29